# ssh2_sftp cannot find files with $ sign as part of the name

Tags: php, ssh2-sftp

I am running into a bit of a situation here. I have an external party that provides certain files to me via SFTP. These files' names contain some special characters in them. For example

```
4569278-04?$example$.jpg
```

The problem is, by doing the following, it cannot find the file.

```
$remoteFilePath = 'download/images/4569278-04?$example$.jpg';
            
file_exists("ssh2.sftp://" . intval($handle). "/" . $remoteFilePath);
```

There are however, other files on the SFTP that I am able to fetch. They don't contain any "special" characters as part of the filenames though.

I tried quoting the filename in single quotes as well, but no luck there. Also quite interesting that I didn't run into this issue using [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib).

At the moment, I don't have the flexibility of changing the implementation anytime soon or ask the third party to change the filenames.

Comment: Have you tried the backslash quote, e.g. "\$example\$.jpg"

Comment: Yes, also doesn't work

Comment: Considering the filename passed into the "file_exists()" function is a URL, perhaps the filename needs to be url-encoded. Have you tried: `$remoteFilePath = urlencode($remoteFilePath);` Not sure, but maybe only the part after the query character (question mark) needs to be url-encoded, but it likely won't hurt to url-encode the entire string.

Comment: Yep, tried that and didn't work too.